# How to open URL from within dependency but only once upon adding it to the project

Tags: maven, netbeans

I want to build maven repo on which after adding it to the project it will open URL in the default browser.

Comment: Are talking about a Maven repository or a dependency? Do you mean a specific IDE? For adding some xml to the pom.xml will not open you a browser.

Comment: I want to have a repo and in it a jar, after which Ii add to the project it will open URL but just that one time after adding.

Comment: This cannot be done in Maven as Maven is just a command line tool. If you are looking for a plugin/functionality of a specific IDE like Eclipse or IntelliJ, please be more specific (although I also doubt that you will find something out of the box for that)

Comment: Thinking about NetBeans IDE